# Evaluate the Cubed Root

Tags: modular-arithmetic

So I have a question as follows

Evaluate the cube root of $2 \mod 59$

So it is my understanding that I need to find $x$, where $x^3 = 2 \mod{59}$

I have tried different values for $x$ all the way up to $30$ and I still haven't found one that satisfies the equation. Can anyone help me out? Is there an easier and more efficient method of calculate cubed roots?

Comment: My answer at http://math.stackexchange.com/a/632977/589 says how.

Comment: How is this question different from your previous one? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632971/modular-arithmetic-evaluate-find-square-roots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another easier way to solve this is use simple arithmetic, observing that $$120 ≡ 2 \mod 59$$ so you have just to find two cubes whose product is $120$ (you have already calculated them up to 30, right?):

$$
2^3 = 8 \mod 59 \\
19^3 = 6859 ≡ 15 \mod 59
$$

so the product of the roots will give your solution.

Comment: Okay I have another question:Evaluate the cube root of 2 mod 83.

85 = 2 mod 83, 85 = 5 * 17

So I get 

14^3 = 5 mod 83

I can't find an x for which x^3 = 17  mod 83 can you help me out?

Comment: @rewritten, do you think this method is really universal? Is finding $\pmod{59}$ of cubes like $11,13,17,19$  really trivial?

Comment: I can guarantee that a solution exists (as $83≡2\mod 3$), keep trying. The point is not to find any product, but to find an easy one, like 168=8·21.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I don't think the method is universal, but also I don't hink the OP needs an universal method, just hints on how to look for explicit solutions.

Comment: @rewritten I ended up with 2^3 = 8 mod 83 and 25^3 = 21 mod 83

So what do I do now to get my answer for the question? Do I multiply 2^3 * 25^3 and then mod 83 it?

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

As $\displaystyle2^6=64\equiv5\pmod{59},2^{12}\equiv5^2,2^{18}\equiv5^3\equiv7,$

$\displaystyle 2^{30}=2^{18}\cdot2^{12}\equiv7\cdot25\equiv175\equiv-2\pmod{59}$

As $\displaystyle(2,59)=1,$

using $\#12$ of [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Congruence.html),   $\displaystyle2^{29}\equiv-1\pmod{59}\implies 2$ is a primitive root $\pmod{59}$

Apply [Discrete Logarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteLogarithm.html) to convert the problem to [Linear Congruence Equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearCongruenceEquation.html)

Comment: See also(http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Solution_of_Linear_Congruence).

Comment: Once you have $2^{30} = (2^{10})^3 ≡ -2$, just multiply by $-1$ to obtain $(-(2^{10}))^3 ≡ 2$ so your solution is $-1024 \mod 59$.

Comment: @rewritten, I know. But what I don't know is how to show the solution is unique from there

Comment: In mod 59 (an any modulus a prime $≡ 2 \mod 3$) all numbers are cubes (see for instance  http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0604465v2). So cubed root is unique.