# Deriving formula for when a number will have a unique cubed root

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have a question as follows and I am pretty sure it is going to come up on my exam

Under what condition on $p$ will a number have a unique cube root $\mod p$, where $p$ is a prime number? Derive an explicit formula for finding cube roots when this condition is met.

So am I correct in saying that p will have a cubed root if $p = 2$ $\mod 3$? I am not sure why this is the case but I remember seeing it somewhere. Whether this is the case or not can someone help me out with this question with a good explanation of the answer? I would really appreciate it

Comment: As there is at least one primitive root use  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/637119/evaluate-the-cubed-root/637135#637135

Comment: Do you want to know if every number has a unique cube root mod $p$ or if there exists a number that has a unique cube root mod $p$?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee would you be able to give more detail as to how I can apply that answer to this question?

Comment: @user1552404, Now I really fear if you could understand my other solution properly. Now I have added a solution here. Please feel free to get back tome  if you have any confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle x^3=a\pmod p\  \ \  \  (1)$

Now as $p$ is prime, $p$ [has](http://math453fall2008.wikidot.com/lecture-24) at least one primitive root, say $g$

Applying [Discrete Logarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteLogarithm.html) wrt $g\pmod p,$

$\displaystyle 3\cdot$ind$_gx\equiv$ind$_ga\pmod{p-1}\  \  \ \ (2)$ which is a Linear Congruence Equation.

Using [Linear congruence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruence_theorem), $(2)$ hence $(1)$ will be solvable iff ind$_ga$ is divisible by $(3,p-1)=d$. In that case, there will be exactly $d$ solutions

If $p\equiv2\pmod3,p-1\equiv1\implies d=(p-1,3)=1$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: express your number as a power of the primitive root. What power(s) can the cube root be? Remember that the order of the multiplicative group mod $p$ is $p-1.$